# Существует ли вложенное деструктурирование?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Как можно вытащить внутреннее значение объекта несколько раз?

**Например:**

Есть объект

> const a = { a: { b: { c: 'hi' } } }

Необходимо получить сразу c.

> const { b: { c } } = a;

Я предполагал что-то подобное, но двоеточие по спецификации - указывает на имя для переопределения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В случае, если после двоеточия идет объект, то это не присваивание имени

( [почитать](https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring#%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) )

```js
const a = { a: { b: { c: 'hi' } } }
const {a: {b: {c}}} = a
console.log(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Если обратиться к [спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-runtime-semantics-destructuringassignmentevaluation) в случае шаблона объекта применяются следующие [правила](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-runtime-semantics-propertydestructuringassignmentevaluation):

1. `AssignmentProperty : IdentifierReference Initializer`
   Если указывается идентификатор и, опционально, инициализатор = идет попытка создания переменной, если деструктуризацию предваряют ключевые слова `let`, `const`, `var`, и попытка установки переменной значения, в случае их отсутствия

   Пример:

   ```js
   // идентификатор `a`, 
   // в результате создана константа `a`
   const {a} = {a: 1};
   console.log('a', a);

   // идентификатор `c`, с инициализатором
   // в результате создана константа c со значением по умолчанию
   // так как в присваиваемом объекте отсутствует поле `c`
   const {c = 10} = {a};
   console.log('c', c);
   ```
2. `AssignmentProperty : PropertyName : AssignmentElement`
   В случае присутствия двоеточия идет попытка деструктуризации конкретного свойства с именем `PropertyName`. И вся деструктуризация повторяется для конкретного значения свойства с именем `PropertyName`.

   ```js
   // PropertyName `a`, 
   // На втором шаге: идентификатор `b` - деструктуризация закончена: 
   // создана константа `b`
   const {a:b} = {a: {b:1}};
   console.log('b', b);

   // Так как в присваиваемом объекте отсутствует поле `a` - работает инициализатор, 
   // и дальнейшая деструктуризация проводится уже на нем
   // создается константа `a`
   const {a:{c:a} = {c:12}} = {b};
   console.log('a', a);
   ```

---

Если подытожить: деструктурирование осуществляется рекурсивно пока не будет указан конкретный идентификатор.